# How to change a label text during a for loop in IOS swift4?

Tags: ios, for-loop, uilabel, swift4

I want to change/reload my label on activity indicator while I am running the for loop. But I am unable to change my label text.

```
for i in 0..<(tempAry.count)
{
  self.tempLbl.text = "\(i) Task Completed"
}
```

Comment: this changes the text in one rendering cycle, so you are going to end up with the last number printed.. you have to show the rest of the code

Comment: your result for this will be "(count-1) TaskCompleted" the last result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define globally.

```
var count = 0
var timer: Timer?
```

In `viewDidLoad` method add timer.

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updating), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Outside `ViewDidLoad` method put below method.

```
@objc func updating() {
        if count >= 100 - 1{
            timer?.invalidate()
            timer = nil
            return
        }

        count += 1
        self.title = "\(count) Task Completed"
    }
```

Actually previously added answer is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't visible label text from for loop every time, You will visible only last index label.

> > Time complexity of this for loop is **O(1)** so execution time of whole for loop is in milliseconds.

So better way to use the Timer to show the text on the label.